# Change Tracking in my application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, change-tracking

I have just recently begun writing an application in ASP.NET MVC4.

My application has objects/models relating with each other in the entire application.

I want to add a cool new feature `change tracking / event logging` to this application, kinda like facebook notifications.

Basically, I know I need to build an audit log of events taking place in the application, but what is a `high-level` way to implement this ?

Do I just insert manually into my `Audit table` after every database operation, or is there a more graceful way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more graceful way would be to subscribe to the **SavingChanges** event.

Read [Basic Auditing for Dynamic Data with Entity Framework 4.x](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2012/02/basic-auditing-for-dynamic-data-with.html) for a nice introductory run through.